# Delta function integral tricks

Tags: integration, dirac-delta, quantum-mechanics

Often in physics we have integrals like the following containing delta functions inside derivatives.
[image]

Eventhough I know the 'correct' way to compute this integral is to integrate by parts until the delta function is alone and *only then* see that it gives this result, in this case it also works to compute the integral by simply "removing the integral and dx' and replacing all x' with x".

I was wondering if this 'trick' only works with delta functions that are on their own, and with delta functions who can be integrated by parts like this but with 0 boundary conidtions, or whether this trick of simply "removing the integral and replacing all x' with x " works more generally.

Comment: I don’t understand the “trick”, the definition of $\delta’$ is $\int \delta’\phi=-\phi’(0)$ if $\phi$ is smooth. You’re not allowed to actually integrate by parts; rather the definition is written to mimic integration by parts.

Comment: The expression on the right-hand side is NOT the same as the one obtained by "removing the integral and $dx'$ and replacing all $x'$ with $x"$.  And what is $x''$?

Comment: Sorry the x'' is just x '' with ending quotation marks, as in the right-hand side is just the left hand side if you remover the $\int$ $dx$ and replace all the $x'$ with $x$.

Comment: Well, the integrand has a first partial on $\psi$; the result has a second partial.  So, do you see the flaw in your assertion now?

Comment: But using the 'rule' I just stated you have the $\partial /\partial x$ then the $ \partial \psi/\partial x$ that combine into a second partial.

Answer (score 1):

You are overthinking it. Due diligence: First note you want all derivatives in your active variable, namely *x'*.

Use the evident identity (prove it!),
$$
(\partial_x + \partial_{x'}) ~ \delta (x-x')=0.
$$

You then have
$$
\int \!\! dx' ~~\partial_x \delta (x-x') ~ \partial_{x'} \psi(x')=
-\int \!\! dx' ~~(\partial_{x'} \delta (x-x') )~ \partial_{x'} \psi(x')\\  =
\int \!\! dx' ~~  \delta (x-x') ~ \partial_{x'}^2 \psi(x') =\partial_x^2\psi(x').
$$

Comment: Thank you for this interesting way of approaching it rigerously. However I was wondering if the properties of the delta function meant that this 'trick' was valid for anything more than the trivial cases that I mentioned or whether it was just a 'coincidence' for those cases.

Comment: Frankly, I did not understand your "trick" as it was not stated clearly enough--I'm not sure it *can*.

Comment: I guess a better way of stating it is just simply remove the delta function from the integrand and replace all x' with x and that's it. Without doing any rearrangement first.

Comment: I guess I'll take it as a coincidence then

Comment: Sigh. Take the derivative  w.r.t. *x* out of the integral, since it has nothing to do with the integration variable *x'*. Collapse the integral. Apply the derivative then. Is *this* your trick? Of course it works.